# Why there is a red x on my Java Resources directory?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I created a web project using maven in eclipse 4.4.2, my spring version is 3.2.7.RELEASE, I can run the project smoothly in tomcat 7, however, there is a red x on my Java Resources directory, and I just can't find any thing wrong.
my project tree:
[image: my project tree]

my Java Build Path conf:
[image: Java Build Path conf]

my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.alex</groupId>
  <artifactId>mywebapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>mywebapp Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>   
  <properties>
    <spring.version>3.2.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <finalName>mywebapp</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

my applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.alex.mywebapp" />

    <bean id="helloWorldService" class="com.alex.mywebapp.HelloWorldService">
        <property name="name" value="Alex" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

there is no problem in my console, anybody has some idea?

thank you in advance!

Comment: Check in the tab called markers. It will explain the problem. From eclipse, click on Window > show view > other > markers.

Comment: Look in the Problems view (simpler than the Markers view)

Comment: have you tried to make a clean project?

Comment: @AleksandrM, update maven project solved my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like FMC said, the *Markers tab* will tell you the warnings and the errors with their description. Sometimes this error is associated with project facets.**Properties>Project facets>Dynamic Web module** (uncheck) **and Java** (change to what's installed or set in your pom)**> OK**.